# select drop down in struts2, migrating from struts1 to struts2

Tags: struts2, struts-1, struts1

Below is Struts1 code snippet from jsp

```
<logic:notEmpty name="user" property="myLanguages" scope="session">
                       <html:select name="user" property="defaultLanguage">
                         <html:optionsCollection label="languageName" name="user" property="myLanguages" value="languageCode"/>
                       </html:select>
</logic:notEmpty>
```

Below is Struts2 (2.5.16 version) code snippet from jsp which is not working

```
<s:if test="%{#session.user.myLanguages != null && #session.user.myLanguages != ''}">
                          <s:select list="{#session.user.myLanguages}"
                                      listKey="languageCode" listValue="languageName"
                                      name="user"  value="defaultLanguage"/>
</s:if>
```

Below is the scriplet code from jsp

```
<%
User user = (User) session.getAttribute("user");
Vector vMyLang = user.getMyLanguages();
        System.out.println("logon.jsp:vMyLang--- "+vMyLang);
        if(null != vMyLang){
            System.out.println("logon.jsp:vMyLang-----  "+vMyLang.size());//here output(i.e size) is 20
        }
%>
```

**So values exists in the session but i'm not able to get using strut2 tags**,
there are no error/exception in the logs

Struts1 code is working fine, Struts2 code is not working(i mean drop down is not shown in the UI)

Please help me out what mistake i have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with below piece of code

```
<s:if test="%{#session.user.myLanguages != null}">
                          <s:select list="%{#session.user.myLanguages}"
                                      listKey="languageCode" listValue="languageName"
                                      value="%{#session.user.defaultOperaLanguage}/>
</s:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSP and scriptlet are not equivalent.

In your scriptlet you're *calling* a method named `myLanguages()`.

In your `<s:if />` tag you're *attempting* to call a method named `getMyLanguages()`.

Since you're not following JavaBean naming conventions you cannot use the syntactic sugar OGNL provides and you'll need to actually call the method.

*Note: You should follow JavaBean naming conventions; they're a convention for a reason. Any Java that relies on reflection, like OGNL, requires it.*

Comment: sorry Dave Newton its my copy paste problem in the question, i'm following the JavaBean conventions, i have updated the question

Comment: @learningknowledge I'd have to play with it then; do you have a minimal working example w/ a pom so I can try it locally? Should be easy enough to replicate if it's just an OGNL problem.

Comment: example w/ a pom i dont understand this

Comment: ... A minimal example demonstrating the problem, with a `pom.xml` file so it can be easily built and replicated.

Comment: the migration which i'm working is not maven project, but the code for struts1 is working fine and migration code(struts2 code) is not working

Comment: @learningknowledge Understood. What I'm asking for is a minimal example showing the failure, e.g., the new project's pom, an action that sets up dummy (but equivalent types), and the view layer. Should be 5-10m of work. Otherwise *I* have to set up everything, ensure the versions of everything match (you provide no version info), guess at the data types, etc. to see if it works. This is onerous. If *you* provide it, I can run and test within minutes, and answer the question.

Comment: Thanks Dave Newton